# Ubuntu Virtualbox share folder to host-only network

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, samba

Is it possible to share folders with samba only to one network?
It bothers me that the complete network can see my shares for the VMs.

An other posibility could be a subnet for the VM-host, but my skills are not good enough to do that.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you have concern as you could lock down users that can use it and would assume that regardless of the network you would want them to have access, but also do not know what your network topography looks like. 
You can however set your hosts allow, here is link that shows some examples: http://oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch04_06.html

Comment: thx, that was the solution i searched for

Answer (score 0):

Shared folders set up through the Guest Additions are only visible to the VM, not to the whole network. Before starting the VM, click on it, then on the right-hand panel select `Shared folder`, and then click on the `Plus` sign. That's all.

Comment: the problem is, that i have to do this with every vm in my collenction